# How can I reference a constructor object from an array?

Tags: c#, winforms

*This is probably worded extremely weird because I'm a beginner at coding and C#*

Not sure if the title really reflects the problem because I'm just really confused. I have this project where I have to create a basic healthcare billing management system. I think I've gotten it basically done but I am having issues referencing the patients and updating that specific person's account balance. To start I have a class with a constructor (with a name parameter), two properties (name and account), and two methods debit and credit. On a button click event it is supposed to take a patient from a Listbox, the price of his Service from a radio box, and then charge that patient's account. I think my main problem is referencing my Patient class file to have a specific patient charged, im a little confused on this part. I have this inizilization code to access my class { Patient pat = new Patient("jerry"); } I had to put "jerry" there as a placeholder to get my code to work to test out the debit and credit. I have no idea what to put there instead of the placeholder so it can reference the actual selected patient.

[image]

Here is my code:
CLASS FILE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project_4
{
    class Patient
    {
        private string _name;
        private decimal _account;

        public Patient(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
            _account = 0.00m;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

        public decimal Account
        {
            get { return _account; }
        }

        public void Debit(decimal amount)
        {
            _account += amount;
        }

        public void Credit(decimal amount)
        {
            _account -= amount;
        }

    }
}
```

MAIN FILE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static Project_4.Patient;

namespace Project_4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //array of patient objects
        Patient[] patients =
        {
            new Patient ("Allan Hall          "), //had to do it this way, the formatting was weird and the tabs were not lining up
            new Patient ("John Jacobson"),
            new Patient ("Fatima Singh"),
            new Patient ("Alicia Williams")
        };

        Patient pat = new Patient("jerry");

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //shows all patients and their account balance
        private void allAccountsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AccountDisplay accDisplay = new AccountDisplay();

            foreach (Patient patient in patients)
            {
                accDisplay.accountDisplayLstBox.Items.Add(patient.Name + "\t" + patient.Account.ToString("C"));
            }

            accDisplay.ShowDialog();
        }

        //when cicked it should charge the selected patients with the selected service
        private void chargeServiceBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AccountUpdate accUpdate = new AccountUpdate();
            string selectedService = "";
            decimal selectedServiceAmt = 0.00m;

            if (patientLstBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = patientLstBox.SelectedIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a patient from the list box");
            }

            if (annualPhysicalRBtn.Checked)
            {
                selectedService = annualPhysicalRBtn.Text;
                selectedServiceAmt = 89.00m;
                pat.Debit(selectedServiceAmt);
            }
            else if (vaccinationsRBtn.Checked)
            {
                selectedService = vaccinationsRBtn.Text;
                selectedServiceAmt = 159.00m;
                pat.Debit(selectedServiceAmt);
            }
            else if (minorIllnessRBtn.Checked)
            {
                selectedService = minorIllnessRBtn.Text;
                selectedServiceAmt = 99.00m;
                pat.Debit(selectedServiceAmt);
            }
            else if (minorInjuryRBtn.Checked)
            {
                selectedService = minorInjuryRBtn.Text;
                selectedServiceAmt = 139.00m;
                pat.Debit(selectedServiceAmt);
            }

            accUpdate.accountUpdateLbl.Text = "Patient: " + pat.Name + "\n" + "Service: " + selectedService + "\n" + "Amount charged to account: " + selectedServiceAmt.ToString("C") + "\n" + "Account Balance: " + pat.Account.ToString("c");
            accUpdate.ShowDialog();

        }

        //when click it should pay an amount to the patients account balance
        private void pay4ServiceBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal payment = 0.00m;
            AccountUpdate accUpdate = new AccountUpdate();

            if (patientLstBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = patientLstBox.SelectedIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a patient from the list box");
            }


            if (amountTxtBox.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                payment = decimal.Parse(amountTxtBox.Text);
                pat.Credit(payment);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a patient from the list box");
            }

            accUpdate.accountUpdateLbl.Text = "Patient: " + pat.Name + "\n" + "Amount credited to account: " + payment.ToString("C") + "\n" + "Account Balance: " + pat.Account.ToString("c");
            accUpdate.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: I don't see how your `patients` array is connected to `patientLstBox` in the code you provided.  Typically it would be something like `patientLstBox.DataSource = patients;` and then `patientLstBox.SelectedItem` will actually be a `Patient` object.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, where exactly would I put that? My book has examples that I'm supposed to reference but they are pretty basic.

Comment: @BenVoigt they're adding the items manually in an iterator within `allAccountsBtn_Click`.

Comment: @Tacoタコス I'm talking about `patientLstBox` not `accountDisplayLstBox`

Comment: @NessFalcom: In your `public Form1()` constructor, after the call to `InitializeComponents` would be a good place for `patientLstBox.DataSource = patients;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the proper `Patient` instance from your `patients` array - based on the user's selection of the patient.

In a real system the patients would be managed elsewhere, in a patient repository of some sort. The form will get the patient list from the repository, as well as the patient objects. In your case, the repository is just the patients array.

Comment: would i reference the array in this section of the code?  Patient pat = new Patient();

Answer (score 0):

In modern programming, there is a tendency to separate your data (= model) from the way that the data is displayed (= view). To connect these two, usually an adapter class is needed. This adapter class is usually called the viewmodel. These three classes together are abbreviated as MVVM. Consider to read some background information about this.

So you have a sequence of Patients, and you want to display all Patients. The operator selects a Patient, and after selecting other items, you want to access the "selected patient"

In winforms, when displaying sequences of similar objects, the separation of model and view is done using `DataSource`. You will find that controls that can display "lists" have a property DataSource. With this property you can tell the control which objects must be shown. Other properties tell the control how the controls must be displayed.

In your case: you want to display a sequence of Patients. You don't want to display everything of the Patient, you only want to display the Patient's Name. If an operator selects the Name of a Patient, he selects the Patient with the Name.

To tell the ListBox which property of the Patient must be shown, use the base class property [ListControl.DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=net-5.0)

You can use visual studio designer to inform the ListBox which property must be displayed, you can also do this in the constructor of your form

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // listBoxPatients shows the value of property Name:
    this.listBoxPatients.DisplayMember = nameof(Patient.Name);
    ...
}
```

This has the advantage that if you decide to change the name of the property, this will automatically change to.

Of course you have a method to fetch all Patient accounts:

```
IEnumerable<Patient> FetchAllPatientAccounts() {...}
```

The implementation is not part of the question.

Now to display the patient it is enough to put the patients into a List, and assign this to the DataSource:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<Patient> DisplayedPatients
{
    get => (IReadOnlyCollection<Patient> this.ListBoxPatients.DataSource;
    set => this.listBoxPatients.DataSource = value;
}

void InitializeDisplayedPatients()
{
    IEnumerable<Patient> patients = this.FetchAllPatientAccounts();
    this.DisplayedPatients = patients.ToList();
}
```

And presto: the names of all Patients are displayed. I decided to interface the displayed patients with an `IReadOnlyCollection<Patient>`, because I don't want to Add / Remove patients. Furthermore in your model a Patient is identified by Name, so it's no use to give the Patient an index: the value of `Patient[4]` is not defined, so we don't implement the notion of index.

The operator can select the name of a Patient. When he Selects the name, internally the complete databound Patient is selected:

```
Patient CurrentPatient => (Patient)this.ListBoxPatients.SelectedItem;
```

Probably not part of your model, but if you want to select several Patients:

```
IEnumerable<Patient> SelectedPatients => this.ListBoxPatients.SelectedItems
    .Cast<Patient>();
```

Of course you will also need to get the amount of the selected Service:

```
decimal SelectedServiceAmount => ... // interpret the radio buttons
                                     // not part of the question.
```

So after the operator presses the ChargeService / PayService buttons:

```
void ChargeCurrentPatient()
{
    Patient currentPatient = this.CurrentPatient;
    decimal serviceAmount = this.SelectedServiceAmount;
    currentPatieny.Credit(serviceAmount);
    this.DisplayedAmount = currentPatient.Amount;
}
```

PayService will be similar

To display the amount in the text box:

```
decimal displayedAmount;
const string displayAmountFormatString = "...";

decimal DisplayedAmount
{
    get => this.displayedAmount;
    set
    {
        this.displayedAmount = value;
        this.TextBoxDisplayedAmount = value.ToString(displayAmountFormatString);
    }
}
```

And of course the button handler:

```
void OnButtonChargeServiceClicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ChargeCurrentPatient();
}
```

By the way, did you see, that because I always separate the model, from the view, most methods in your forms will be very small. Changes in your user interface will have little impact on your code.

For instance: what if you have too many services, and you can't show them as radio buttons, but need to show them in a ComboBox. This will be very similar to the ListBox:

Constructor:

```
this.comboBoxServices.DisplayMember = nameof(Service.Description);
```

Displaye all Services is similar to the ListBox:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<Service> DisplayedServices
{
    get => (IReadOnlyCollection<Service>)this.comboboxServices.DataSource;
    set => this.comboBoxServices.DataSource = value;
}

Service SelectedService => (Service)this.comboBoxServices.SelectedItem;
```

PayService and ChargeService will not change